# Why are the confidence intervals so large for the difference of differences?

Tags: confidence-interval, glmm, difference-in-difference, lsmeans, back-transformation

I have run a generalized linear mixed effects model with the glmmTMB package to determine if there is an interaction between two categorical predictors, treatment and location, in predicting the number of birds detected.

```
mod3 <- glmmTMB(sum.50 ~ location*trtmt + julian2 + min_aft_sunrise2 + mintemp2 + (1|week) + (1|site:day), data = wbnu_sub, ziformula=~1, family=poisson)
```

I'm interested in looking at comparing the levels of treatment and location to each other, so I have used the emmeans package to computer the difference of differences.

```
mod3.emm <- emmeans(mod3, ~ location|trtmt, adjust = "none")
locdiffs <- contrast(mod3.emm, "revpairwise", adjust = "mvt")
locdiffs
```

```
trtmt = pulsed_nofood:
 contrast   estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 near - far   -0.273 0.586 124 -0.467  0.6416 

trtmt = constant:
 contrast   estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 near - far    2.024 0.376 124  5.381  <.0001 

trtmt = pulsed_food:
 contrast   estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 near - far    2.737 0.728 124  3.758  0.0003 

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale.
```

```
c <- confint(contrast(locdiffs, "revpairwise", by = NULL, adjust = "mvt"))
c
```

```
 contrast                                          estimate    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 near - far,constant - near - far,pulsed_nofood       2.297 0.696 124    0.652     3.94
 near - far,pulsed_food - near - far,pulsed_nofood    3.011 0.935 124    0.801     5.22
 near - far,pulsed_food - near - far,constant         0.714 0.820 124   -1.223     2.65

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: mvt method for 3 estimates
```

These results seemed okay, except for when I back-transformed these I realized that the confidence intervals are gigantic!

```
c.response <- confint(contrast(locdiffs, "revpairwise", by = NULL, adjust = "mvt", type = "response"))

contrast                                          ratio    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 near / far,constant / near / far,pulsed_nofood     9.95  6.93 124    1.919     51.6
 near / far,pulsed_food / near / far,pulsed_nofood 20.31 18.99 124    2.228    185.1
 near / far,pulsed_food / near / far,constant       2.04  1.67 124    0.294     14.2

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: mvt method for 3 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

And the same is for the locdiffs:

```
locdiffs.response <- contrast(mod3.emm, "revpairwise", adjust = "mvt", type = "response")

trtmt = pulsed_nofood:
 contrast    ratio     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 near / far  0.761  0.446 124    0.238     2.43

trtmt = constant:
 contrast    ratio     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 near / far  7.566  2.845 124    3.594    15.93

trtmt = pulsed_food:
 contrast    ratio     SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 near / far 15.447 11.252 124    3.653    65.32

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

Why is that? Does it have to do something with the log of differences turns into a ratio? If so, why does that mean the standard errors become gigantic?

Comment: This is a fundamental property of logarithms.  But in light of your stated objective--"determine if there is an interaction between two categorical predictors"--does it matter how wide the confidence intervals are?

Comment: @whuber, I'm having trouble understanding it since I never counted more than 5 birds at a site. Not sure how to explain it to someone in that context.

Comment: Note that if you compute exp(.65) and exp(3.94) you get about 1.9 and 51 — consistent with intervals after back-transforming. So this looks right in transforming log odds ratios to odds ratios. Understand that odds are defined as p/(1-p) and you are taking the ratio of two such quantities with only 5 observations, you can expect CIs to be very wide because you can’t accurately estimate anything with very little data.

Comment: When you say odds are defined as p/(1-p) what is p from? Also, I had more than 5 observations, I had 11-12 for each treatment (and each treatment is replicated across sites).